# In App downloadable content

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I'm trying implement a kind of private 'cloud store' for may web application. Let me explain, I have 'reports' (a file containing queries etc) which can be installed on a client pc. Normally, we e-mail them the files to end users whenever we create new ones and they manually import them into the app (using standard file upload in any browser).

Now we want to take it a step further and create a page which will pull a list of files from our site, eg. www.me.com/reports. The app will go through the list, compare to those installed and display new ones, updated ones etc. An end user could then just click on a button and the files are downloaded on the server and installed.

I'm trying to avoid writing any web server code, I'd prefer to just create a windows authenticated virtual directory that allows for file listing (or something close to this). I'm thinking maybe some javascript that will silently download the file to the client, then upload it back to the intranet iis server. All done without user interaction. Is this even possible?

I'd like to get anyone's thoughts on how something like this could be implemented, and what pitfalls I should watch out for.

Thanks
JK

Comment: Pitfall: _"all done without user interaction"_ in a web browser context? You can look into DOM storage et al ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=vs.85).aspx) , [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)) instead of file system/OS (security).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into DOM storage, sounds promising. Actually now that I think about it, user interaction might not be needed. The user could trigger a process on the server (if the server has web access) that can download the file and install it.